# How does PHP interpret local paths and where does it open files?

Tags: php, file, fwrite

I'm trying to figure out how a WordPress theme works. For this, I want to write to a file from various functions. The file is at the root of the site.

```
fwrite(fopen("output.txt", "a"), "Test output\n");
```

From `/test.php`, this outputs to `/output.txt`. I'd like to write the value of a variable in a deeply-nested function. Copy/pasting the above code outputs to somewhere I can't find. This:

```
fwrite(fopen("/output.txt", "a"), "Test output\n");
```

doesn't work, either. It raises:

`Warning: fopen(/output.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /public_html/test.php on line 17`

`Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /public_html/test.php on line 17`

The manual specifies some stuff about schemes and wrappers, but doesn't say very much about paths.

> If PHP has decided that filename specifies a local file, then it will try to open a stream on that file. The file must be accessible to PHP, so you need to ensure that the file access permissions allow this access. If you have enabled `safe mode`, or `open_basedir`, further restrictions may apply.

How do I properly reference the path I want, and how does PHP choose where to write with a relative path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using absolute paths, the path is relative to the index.php of wordpress. To access a file that is stored in the same folder as your php file use the global constant [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/de/language.constants.predefined.php):

```
fwrite(fopen(__DIR__ ."/output.txt", "a"), "Test output\n");
```

`__DIR__` will give you the absolute path to the current php script.

Comment: What about absolute paths? How do I do those properly?

Comment: `__DIR__` will give you an absolute path

Comment: :) just try it! you'll get something like `/var/www/foo/bar`